# uploading mixed data from csv into a numpy array in python

Tags: python

I have a csv file that contains 10 columns and 6 rows that I want to convert into a numpy array. Although it loads, I cannot use the data right now and I think I am missing a step.

My code right now looks like this

```
import numpy as np

filename = "test_ioc.csv"

# open file
f=open(filename)

# initialize this 
myfile = [] 

# Convert to numpy array
mat = np.vstack([signal for signal in f.readlines()])
print mat
```

alternatively, I have also done this:

```
import numpy as np

filename = "test_ioc.csv"

# open file
f=open(filename)

# initialize this 
myfile = [] # empty nested list that is the big container, this contains all the rows

# f.readlines, and for each line,
for line in f.readlines():

#create a list for each row
row = [] # empty list for row items, each row has 2 lists

# line.strip, line.split, and for each i in this:
for eye in line.strip().split():

    # convert elements into floats

    row.append(eye) # append each item to list 'row'


# append all the parts row to the list myfile that you created
myfile.append(row) #append list to my file

print myfile

# now that you have your gigantic list myfile, convert to it to numpy array
a = np.array(myfile) #convert the list into a numpy array

# slice accordingly!
x = a[:,0] #first column
y = a[:,1] #second column
f.close()
```

The first one gives me an output like this:

```
print a
    [['2043l0.wav,0.115,0.169,0.222,0.23,2043l0.wav,0.21,0.169,0.238,0.23']
 [ 'dn2001l0.wav,0.105,0.161,0.242,0.222,dn2001l0.wav,0.153,0.176,0.207,0.207']
 ['2694l0.wav,0.13,0.192,0.33,0.314,2694l0.wav,0.192,0.184,0.207,0.238']
 ['2641l0.wav,0.123,0.146,0,0.407,2641l0.wav,0.199,0.199,0.199,0.176']
 ['2622l0.wav,0.284,0.353,0.582,0.582,2622l0.wav,0.268,0.161,0.176,0.184']
 ['dn2047l0.wav,0.12,0.23,0.368,0.322,dn2047l0.wav,0.369,0.169,0.207,0.222']]
```

I really need to split my rows further into 2 sets of 4, convert each number in each row into a float but I am new to python and just want to be able to do some basic operations on my data and graph it using matplotlib. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was you were reading whole lines not splitting the data by comma so you ended up with a line per array, you would need to split on the delimiter so you split into individual elements:

```
mat = np.vstack([signal.split(",") for signal in f)])
```

Or let the csv lib do the parsing:

```
import  csv
mat = np.vstack(csv.reader(f))))
```

But there is a numpy way to read from a file using [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt):

```
import  numpy as np

arr = np.loadtxt("in.csv",delimiter=",",dtype=object)

print(arr)
```

Which would give you an array of arrays:

```
[['2043l0.wav' '0.115' '0.169' '0.222' '0.23' '2043l0.wav' '0.21' '0.169'
  '0.238' '0.23']
 ['dn2001l0.wav' '0.105' '0.161' '0.242' '0.222' 'dn2001l0.wav' '0.153'
  '0.176' '0.207' '0.207']
 ['2694l0.wav' '0.13' '0.192' '0.33' '0.314' '2694l0.wav' '0.192' '0.184'
  '0.207' '0.238']
 ['2641l0.wav' '0.123' '0.146' '0' '0.407' '2641l0.wav' '0.199' '0.199'
  '0.199' '0.176']
 ['2622l0.wav' '0.284' '0.353' '0.582' '0.582' '2622l0.wav' '0.268' '0.161'
  '0.176' '0.184']
 ['dn2047l0.wav' '0.12' '0.23' '0.368' '0.322' 'dn2047l0.wav' '0.369'
  '0.169' '0.207' '0.222']]
```

There is also [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) which gives you a few more options including creating a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html).

```
import numpy as np

headings = [('filename1', "|S20"), ('l0', float), ('l1', float), ('l2', float), ('l3', float),
            ('filename2', "|S10"), ('r0', float), ('r1', float), ('r2', float), ('r3', float)]

arr = np.genfromtxt("in.csv", delimiter=",", dtype=headings)

print(arr)
[ ('2043l0.wav', 0.115, 0.169, 0.222, 0.23, '2043l0.wav', 0.21, 0.169, 
0.238, 0.23)
 ('dn2001l0.wav', 0.105, 0.161, 0.242, 0.222, 'dn2001l0.w', 0.153, 0.176, 0.207, 0.207)
 ('2694l0.wav', 0.13, 0.192, 0.33, 0.314, '2694l0.wav', 0.192, 0.184, 0.207, 0.238)
 ('2641l0.wav', 0.123, 0.146, 0.0, 0.407, '2641l0.wav', 0.199, 0.199, 0.199, 0.176)
 ('2622l0.wav', 0.284, 0.353, 0.582, 0.582, '2622l0.wav', 0.268, 0.161, 0.176, 0.184)
 ('dn2047l0.wav', 0.12, 0.23, 0.368, 0.322, 'dn2047l0.w', 0.369, 0.169, 0.207, 0.222)]
```

You can also lookup by column name like pandas, `arr["filename1"]` etc..

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured out how to answer my question using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'test_ioc.csv'
headings = 'filename', 'l0', 'l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'filename', 'r0', 'r1', 'r2', 'r3'

#data
data = pd.read_csv(filename, names=headings)

print data
```